# Reverse arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

How can I reverse some arrows of the diagram given by the code below?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Tell it where the nodes are
  \node (A) {$A$};
  \node (B) [below=of A] {$B$};
  \node (C) [right=of A] {$C$};
  \node (D) [right=of B] {$D$};
  % Tell it what arrows to draw
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node[left] {\small $i$} (B);
  \draw[-stealth] (B)-- node [below] {\small $g$} (D);
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node [above] {\small $j$} (C);
  \draw[-stealth] (C)-- node [right] {\small $k$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Do you want to add extra arrows or just change the direction of some of the existing arrows?

Comment: Just to change the directions of some/all of them. Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either interchange `-` and the specification of the arrow tip, or you can also interchange the order of the nodes; the following code shows both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {$A$}; 
  \node (B) [below=of A] {$B$}; 
  \node (C) [right=of A] {$C$}; 
  \node (D) [right=of B] {$D$};
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node[left] {\small $i$} (B); 
  \draw[-stealth] (B)-- node [below] {\small $g$} (D); 
  \draw[-stealth] (A)-- node [above] {\small $j$} (C); 
  \draw[-stealth] (C)-- node [right] {\small $k$} (D); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) {$A$}; 
  \node (B) [below=of A] {$B$}; 
  \node (C) [right=of A] {$C$}; 
  \node (D) [right=of B] {$D$};
  \draw[stealth-] (A)-- node[left] {\small $i$} (B); 
  \draw[stealth-] (B)-- node [below] {\small $g$} (D); 
  \draw[-stealth] (C)-- node [above] {\small $j$} (A); 
  \draw[-stealth] (D)-- node [right] {\small $k$} (C); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]